# yup validation, one of three has to be filled out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, yup

I have an issue with some yup validation...
I have a form with a lot of fields - In this form, the user needs to fill in at least one of three fields: Username, Email or Phone

```
const userSchema = yup
  .object()
  .shape({
    username: yup.string().when(['email', 'phone'], {
      is: (email, phone) => !email && !phone,
      then: yup.string().required('Username is required')
    }),
    email: yup.string().email('Please enter a valid email'),
    phone: yup.string().when(['username', 'email'], {
      is: (username, email) => !username && !email,
      then: yup.string().required('Phone is required')
    }),
    password: yup
      .string()
      .min(8, 'Password must be 8 characters long')
      .matches(/[0-9]/, 'Password requires a number')
      .matches(/[a-z]/, 'Password requires a lowercase letter')
      .matches(/[A-Z]/, 'Password requires an uppercase letter')
      .matches(/[^\w]/, 'Password requires a symbol')
      .required('Password is required')
  })
  .required();
```

However, Im getting errors on this: index.js:45 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cyclic dependency

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In yup, it is necessary to arrange dependency fields in a specific order of construction. In your code, `username` depends on field `phone` to validate,  but `phone` depends on `usename` to validate. you must cast and coerce the value in field `phone` before passing it to field `username`, or vice versa

In your case, your schema must be something like:

```
const userSchema = yup
  .object()
  .shape({
  ...
  }, [
  ['username', 'phone'],
  ])
```

You can read more about it [here](https://dev.to/gabrielterriaga/how-to-validate-two-fields-that-depend-on-each-other-with-yup-1ccg)